FormBuilder: Contact dedup is also removing related data that can be multiple rows
When making form with Form Builder, say with an individual fields of last name, first name, etc., we can set dedupe rules. It works with contacts as intended. But it also clears up data from other table that can have multiple data from a contact. Say Contact has many favorites. It would clear up favorite with the same contact and add the latest one added.
Favorites can be same details. Only the contact has rules. Just wondering if that intended or is there a way to restrict removing all previous favorites.
